# bootstrap 4 / jquery - on click of drop down focus on input

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to focus on an input field when I click a bootstrap drop down, I can see the event firing with the alert created but the focus does not move to the search box. can anyone see why?

```js
$("#devSearch").keyup(function() {
  filter = $("#devSearch").val().toUpperCase()
  div = $("#devDropdown")
  a = div.find("a")
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
});
$("#devDD").click(function(){
  alert('yes')
  $('#devSearch').focus();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="devDD" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Devices</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fixed-height" id="devDropdown">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="devSearch" style="width:8rem; margin:0 1rem">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">All Entires</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Big bob</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Little bob</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sausage</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chicken</a>
      <span class="filter-results no-results">Oops, nothing found!<span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/9k63htx4/36/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [shown.bs.dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#events) instead of click event:

```
$("#devDD").on('shown.bs.dropdown', function(e){
       $('#devSearch').focus();
});
```

Moreover, you need to move your **id="devDD"** to the parent **li** element.

Your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9k63htx4/45/)

```js
$("#devSearch").keyup(function() {
    filter = $("#devSearch").val().toUpperCase()
    div = $("#devDropdown")
    a = div.find("a")
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
});
$("#devDD").on('shown.bs.dropdown', function(e){
    $('#devSearch').focus();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="devDD">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Devices</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fixed-height" id="devDropdown">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="devSearch" style="width:8rem; margin:0 1rem">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">All Entires</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Big bob</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Little bob</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sausage</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chicken</a>
      <span class="filter-results no-results">Oops, nothing found!<span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `focus()` event is triggered before the input has fully rendered as interactive in the DOM.  If you add a timeout to your function, it should resolve it.

```
$('#devDD').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#devSearch').focus(); 
    }, 150);
});
```

Alternatively, since the search box is your only input, you could use the [autofocus](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp) attribute:

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" 
   placeholder="Search..." id="devSearch" style="width:8rem; 
   margin:0 1rem" autofocus>
```